How do I create an animated stacked bar chart using matplotlib
I have been trying to create an animated stacked bar chart using matplotlib. Although I have managed to animate each stack element, the output only shows one element at a time. I was also able to manage to get one column of stacked bar at a time. But what I want is to animate each stack element without the displayed element getting cleared before the next element. Will be grateful, if someone can help out.
ps: I have tried both FuncAnimation and ArtistAnimation and failed.:(
Rgds
Nitin

Here is my code.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def bstack(df, title, ylabel, xlabel):
    pp = df.values.tolist()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    def animate(j):
        axlist = []
        for i in range(j):
            yval = df.iloc[i,:].values.tolist()
            stacklabel = df.iloc[i,:].index.tolist()
            for y in range(len(yval)):
                contain = ax.bar(i,yval[y], bottom = sum(yval[:y]),  label = stacklabel[y])
                axlist.append(contain)
        return axlist
    axlist = animate(df.shape[0])
    anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, axlist, interval=500)
    anim.save("stack.gif", writer='ffmpeg')

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'col2':[4,3,2,1], 'col3':[5,6,7,8]})

bstack(df,"mygif","Myplot","Y-axis")


With a FuncAnimation :
R, C = df.shape
ST = df.stack().to_numpy()
CS = df.T.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum().to_numpy()

plt.style.use("ggplot")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    subplot_kw=dict(
        xlim=(-0.5, R - 0.5),
        ylim=(0, df.sum(axis=1).max() + 1),
        xticks=df.index,
    ), figsize=(7, 3),
)

colors = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"]

def stack(i):
    if i == 0:
        pass # empty frame
    else:
        vals = np.zeros(R)
        vals[(i - 1) // C] = ST[i - 1]
        ax.bar(df.index, vals, bottom=CS[(i - 1) % C], fc=colors[(i - 1) % C])

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, stack, frames=len(ST) + 1)


Or this asynchronous version :

How it works in the first animation ?


Thanks. I could not understand this part: vals[(i - 1) // C] = ST[i - 1]

I added an "intermediates" table to explain the logic. vals corresponds to the row-xx columns.

Thanks for the explanation. Based on this understanding, I could come up with modified and simpler version. I will add this as an answer

This is a modification(a simpler version) of the answer already provided by @Timeless. Unfortunately I can't include code in comments. Hence posting this as an answer.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "col2": [4, 3, 2, 1],
        "col3": [5, 6, 7, 8],
    }
)

R, C = df.shape
ST = df.stack().to_numpy()
CS = df.shift(axis=1,fill_value=0).cumsum(axis=1).stack().to_numpy()
xval = pd.DataFrame([[x]*C for x in range(R)]).stack().to_numpy()

plt.style.use("ggplot")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    subplot_kw=dict(
        xlim=(-0.5, R - 0.5),
        ylim=(0, df.sum(axis=1).max() + 1),
        xticks=df.index,
    ), figsize=(7, 3),
)

colors = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"]

def stack(i):
    if i == 0:
        pass # empty frame
    else:
        ax.bar(xval[i-1], ST[i-1], bottom=CS[(i - 1)], fc=colors[(i - 1) % C])


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, stack, frames=len(ST) + 1)
ani.save("stack.gif", writer="ffmpeg")

